# get storm topology status(up or crashed) from code

Tags: apache-storm

I want to know whether my topology is still `running` or `crashed`, and i want to do this using java code, so is there any way to find the same apart from writing a thread which will run parallel to topology and send the heartbeats?

Answer (score 3):

Storm provides rest api for your requirements, you can implement and run another process using it.

Refer to : https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/STORM-UI-REST-API.md